# Pandas time series plot xticklabel

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, python-datetime

I am trying to plot time series data, and label the x-axis by month.
This is the first few of my dataframe:

```
    Time                Value
2012-01-01 00:00:00     1.223
2012-01-01 00:00:30     2.132
2012-01-01 00:01:00     1.417
2012-01-01 00:01:30     1.767
```

And my code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
value = df.value
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = value.plot(x_compat=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator(bymonthday=15))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
plt.show()
```

As suggested in other answers, I already added the (x_compat=True) argument. However, this doesn't give the ticks and ticklabels of my x-axis at all.  How can I fix this?

And I also tried the second way with matplotlib by this

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.plot(df.index, df.value)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator(bymonthday=15))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%M"))
```

But still I can't see the ticklabels in month. It doesn't give me anything on x-axis.

**Answer** I should convert `df.index` using `to_datatime` first.

Comment: It's no minimal example, but in principle you cannot use matplotlib date locators on pandas datetime axes.

Comment: I looked at many examples on stackoverflow and they did this. If this is not acceptable, then how would you make it?

Comment: Which examples "did this"?

Comment: The two solution to this are (1) use matplotlib for plotting (2) use pandas in compatibility mode (`x_compat=True`). Please show in how far the solutions to the duplicates don't work instead of just claiming that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added  'x_compat=True' but still not showing me anything

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest And I also tried the second way with matplotlib, but that is too slow and doesn't give me a plot at all because I have a huge amount of data

Comment: Well, matplotlib can in principle not be slower than the pandas plot, because pandas plots on matplotlib axes. Feel free to make your case reproducible if you need help with plotting with matplotlib.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Hi, I updated my post, could you please take a loot at it? Thank you so much!

Comment: I added another duplicate to the list; you would need to convert your data to datetime for it to be understood as such.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just figured out myself by watching a lot of examples, and now it works. Yes, iI should convert df.index to datatime first.